# What good is setting cURL headers after curl_exec?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I've managed to inherit some Wordpress/PHP code where there is a cURL call like so:

```
$ch = curl_init (); // set up curl
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // the url to request
$response = curl_exec ( $ch )

$headers = array (
                        'Accept: text/html',
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache" 
                );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_close ( $ch );
```

Admittedly I'm rather new to Wordpress and PHP but shouldn't the headers be set BEFORE doing the curl_exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting them after curl_exec does nothing as far as I know... My guess would be that it's an error, or he/she just tried something out and forgot to move the curl_exec, or similar.

Since you have curl_close right after it is just destroyed before anything more is done.